# Prevent WPF combobox clearing selection when itemssource changes

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox

I have a textbox for firstname, a textbox for lastname, and a combobox for displayname.  The displayname is editable so that the user can type in whatever they want.  However, the combobox should display a list of options.

When either textbox changes, the combobox itemssource is updated.  However, if the user previously **selected** a value, then the text property is blanked out.  But if the user had **typed** in a value, the text property remains.  How do i prevent the text value from blanking out?

Here's my code:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        x:Name="MainApp"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainApp}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
                 Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                 Text="{Binding LastName}" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="MyCb" Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="2" 
                  Text="{Binding TheName}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding NameOptions}"
                  IsEditable="True" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public ReadOnly Property NameOptions As List(Of String)
        Get
            Dim result As New List(Of String)
            result.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName))
            result.Add(String.Format("{1}, {0}", FirstName, LastName))
            result.Add(String.Format("{1}, {0} MI", FirstName, LastName))
            Return result
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property TheName As String

    Private _firstName As String
    Public Property FirstName As String
        Get
            Return _firstName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _firstName = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"))
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("NameOptions"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _lastname As String
    Public Property LastName As String
        Get
            Return _lastname
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _lastname = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName"))
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("NameOptions"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here:
[How to disable ItemsSource synchronization with Text property of ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221199/how-to-disable-itemssource-synchronization-with-text-property-of-combobox)

```
public class ComboBox : System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox
{
    private bool ignore = false;
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ignore)
        {
            base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ignore = true;
        try
        {
            base.OnItemsChanged(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            ignore = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set MyCb.SelectedItem to null before NameOptions is updated. SelectedItem supersedes Text and when the ItemsSource is updated it will also try to update the Text supposedly connected to the SelectedItem.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<String> NameOptions 
    {
        get 
        {
            MyCb.SelectedItem = null;   // <--- THIS is the solution. just try it!
            List<String> result = new List<String>();    
            result.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName));
            result.Add(String.Format("{1}, {0}", FirstName, LastName));
            result.Add(String.Format("{1}, {0} MI", FirstName, LastName));
            return result;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private String _theName;
    public String TheName
    {
        get { return _theName; }
        set
        {
            _theName = value;
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TheName"));
            }
        }
    }

    private String _firstName;
    public String FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { 
            _firstName = value; 
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NameOptions"));
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
            }
        }
    }

    private String _lastName;
    public String LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set { 
            _lastName = value; 
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("NameOptions"));
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, this suggestion still clears the displayed value in the combobox. Thanks for trying, but it appears that my bindings are correct and this is how the combobox is designed to work.

Comment: Your code is not quite textbook-like with raising the property changed notification of the combobox's list from another property. Why do you think that this solution still clears the code? Haven't you even tied? I was able to reproduce the behavior you described and discovered that if you never select an item from the list and you enter a freestyle name in the edit field, changing first and last name didn't harm the content of the combobox's edit field. But once you select an item, it will override the edit field's content -- even when the ItemsSource is being rebuilt. Attached my C# code.

Comment: Been out for a while....I tried your suggestion before posting, and tried again just to make sure.  Still doesn't work.  Since this behavior seems to be by design I was going to mark your first answer as the answer, but I do not see it anymore.

Comment: I deleted my first answer because it was not very helpful. Strange thing, that you can't get my code to work. Maybe the behavior of the ComboBox changed durin a new version. I'm using VS 2012 Express here and it showed the problem you described along with my solution perfectly.

Comment: Bump: I'm having the same issue.