# How to disable ItemsSource synchronization with Text property of ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I use the ComboBox for binding to string property of view model. I choose the ComboBox instead of TextBox, because i want to have an option to choose from the list (as a suggestion), but I don't want to change the selected text if the ItemsSource changes.

I tried to set the **IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem** property to false, but when the list of suggestions change (at the position of the selected text), the Text changes to empty.
It seems that the ComboBox has remembered that the entered text was also in the list and when this item disappears, the Text property is also cleared.

So my question is: Is that a bug, or am I doing something wrong? 
If it is a bug, could you suggest some work around?

I created a sample project which preproduces this:

in XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestProject1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  IsEditable="True" Text="{Binding SelectedText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Update list" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,82,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
            Items = new List<string>() { "0", "1", "2" };
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private List<string> _items;
        public List<string> Items {// I use IEnumerable<string> with LINQ, but the effect is the same
            get { return _items; }
            set {
                if (_items != value) {
                    _items = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
                }
            }
        }

        private string _selectedText;
        public string SelectedText {
            get { return _selectedText; }
            set {
                if (_selectedText != value) {
                    _selectedText = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedText");
                }
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var changed = Items.ToList();//clone
            int index = changed.IndexOf(SelectedText);
            if (index >= 0) {
                changed[index] += "a";//just change the currently selected value
            }
            Items = changed;//update with new list
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my fix for that issue:

```
public class ComboBox : System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox
{
    private bool ignore = false;
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ignore)
        {
            base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ignore = true;
        try
        {
            base.OnItemsChanged(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            ignore = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your ItemsSource has changed, raise a property changed on your selected text to refresh the UI.

So in your Items collection setter, make the change:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedText");
```

EDIT: in your example you aren't just changing the ItemSource, you are changing the text of the item that is the currently selected one but having a text binding on the old text. What are you expecting to see/happen? Are you wanting the selected *item* to stay the same, even if its text changes?

Comment: I tried it and did not work. I don't know why should it work?

Comment: It should work because when the ItemsSource changes the concept of which the SelectedItem will be cleared - by RaisingPropertyChanged of your selected item you can restating which item is selected. BUT I've just noticed you are trying to change the *text* of the selected item, and somehow preserve a binding which relies on the text ... this will never work. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Firstly I want to select the text from the list. Then I don't want the selected text be changed after the items source is changed. If the type of the collection (string) was a reference type, then it is a expected behavior. But the string is a value type, therefore after selecting it should remain in the state in which it was selected (new copy).

Comment: In C#, string is a reference type - not a value type.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong kind of control. The Text part of a ComboBox is a text representation of the SelectedItem. If you are intending to select something from the ComboBox but then keep that in isolation away from the state, and changes, that may happen in the ComboBox then you need to detect the SelectedItem change and store that text in a different variable/property.

Comment: uhm, I don't know why I wrote, that string is value type. I know it is not, just didn't realized it. (works like char* in C) But anyway strings are immutable and on any change, a new string is created. Then the changed string has another reference... Am I right?

Comment: But what actually happens is when the Items property raises the event, the setter of the SelectedText is called with value "". So something in external code (binding code of combobox control) sets the value of the Text. Even if I turned the synchronization off.

Comment: I think you need to change your approach, because from what I can gather you aren't interested in binding. You want to respond to a selection by storing the text of that selection, not binding it. Binding is for keeping your UI in step with your model/viewmodel, which you don't want to do for the selected text.

Comment: I thought that the Text property of an editable ComboBox is doing exactly what you described.A TextBox with the possibility of choosing from the list. If I enter any text, which isn't in the list, the Text is not overwritten by empty string if the ItemsSource changes. I think the SelectedValue with SelectedValuePath is for the binding, not the Text. I definitely need to bind to each of these properties to my view model, but not automatically synchronized between them. So as a workaround should I create a custom control which is almost exactly the ComboBox? I thought there is a simpler solution

Comment: Not quite. From the MSDN 'ComboBox.Text Gets or sets the text of the currently selected item'. You may not need a full-blown custom control, just handle the selection differently and store your SelectedText in a differently property - not bound to the Text of the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `Button_Click` like this (commented lines are new):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string tempCopy = SelectedText; // Create a copy of the current value

    var changed = Items.ToList();
    int index = changed.IndexOf(SelectedText);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        changed[index] += "a";
    }
    Items = changed;

    SelectedText = tempCopy; // Replace the selected text with the copy we made
}
```

All this does is makes a copy of `SelectedText` before `Items` changes, and then replaces it once the change has been made.

1. Copy `SelectedText`
2. Modify items source
3. Replace `SelectedText` with the copy